# How to use loop correctly with AutoFilter in my code?

Tags: excel, vba

i'm new in VBA. I am writing macro which is using Autofilter, copy column with results to other sheet and remove duplicates. I'm doing it for 9 warehouses x 3 commodity group = 27 times. Now, i have copied 27 times code as below and it works (but very slow). I know, I should use loop but i'm not sure how to do it.

warehouse: "XXX"

```
Sheets("Apex").Activate
    Lastrow = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        Range("A1:J" & Lastrow).Select
            Selection.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="NIO"
                Selection.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="XXX"
                    Range("A2:A" & Lastrow).Copy
                    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    Selection.AutoFilter
                            Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$500").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

Thank you for help :)

Comment: So changing the criteria 27 times rather than run the filter on 27 different sheets?  Paste all results to `Sheet2` in a list?

Comment: Do you think it would be more efficient? So I need to create 27 sheets and use Advanced filter rather than Autofilter function? Thanks

Comment: No, I'm just asking for clarification of your question - _I'm doing it for 9 warehouses x 3 commodity group = 27 times_  Is your data in one big dataset that you need to filter 27 times and extract data from?  Or is your dataset spread over 27 sheets?  I've no idea how warehouses & commodity groups relate to your data

Comment: Ok, now I understand, sorry :) I have one big dataset 3500 rows and about 10 columns

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to give more detail about your problem. First of all, i can't see the commodity group column index but i try to answer your question as much as i can.

What i understand from your problem is you are using autofilter too much which triggers calculation of workbook each time you run the code and if you have big formulas such as array formulas it can really slow down your file.

The best solution is using arrays but it is not possible for me with the details that you share so i write a loop for your requirements.

Please add a new worksheet to your file with the name of Warehouses and write your warehouse names to A columns one by one and copy below code to a module and run it

```
Sub LoopWareHouses

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Apex")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Warehouses")

Lastrow = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
lrwarehouses = ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

y = 2
For i = 1 To lrwarehouses
    For j = 2 To Lastrow
        If ws.Cells(j, 6) = "NIO" Then
            If ws.Cells(j, 8) = ws3.Cells(i, 1) Then
                ws2.Cells(y, 1) = ws.Cells(j, 1)
                y = y + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next

lr2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Application.Calculate
Do Until Application.CalculationState <> xlDone
    DoEvents
Loop

ws2.Range("A1:A" & lr2).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```